# Python threading but don't wait for longest

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a number of jobs that I need to process at the same time, so looked at threading, this seems to do what I want, but I will always be dragged down by the slowest jobs.  I have the following:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import random

def task(counter, num_things):
    item_num = counter + 1
    if item_num in time_sleep:
        sleep_for = time_sleep[item_num]["sleep"]
    else:
        sleep_for = 1
    print('Start a task %s sleeping for %s' % (item_num, sleep_for))
    time.sleep(sleep_for)
    task_cost = random.randrange(50, 200)
    print('Task cost for task %s: %s' % (item_num, task_cost))


#number of items to do
num_things = 10
#sleep time for different items
#some items may take longer do do
time_sleep = {1: {"sleep": 7}, 10: {"sleep": 10}}

version = "thread"
num_main = 2
for main_counter, main_loop_this in enumerate(range(num_main)):
    start_time = time.time()
    jobs = []
    for things_counter, things_loop_this in enumerate(range(num_things)):
        jobs.append(Thread(target=task, args=(things_counter, num_things)))

    for job in jobs:
        job.start()

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
    end_time = time.time()

    print('Version: %s. It took start %s second(s) to complete.' % (version, end_time - start_time))
```

It takes just over 10 seconds as the slowest is 10 seconds.  Is there  better way to do this?, so I am not held back by the slower item.  I am using Python 2.7 currently.

Comment: Do you need wait for all jobs to finish? Then no, there is no other possibility than to wait for all jobs to finish ... Are your jobs fire and forget (ie you don't need to wait for their result), then remove the `job.join()`. But be aware those jobs may then be cancelled mid-work when the pogram exits.

Comment: What else would you like to do? there are ten "independent" threads running; one of them will be the slowest, but it needs to finish anyway if you want all calculations to be done. ("independent" between quote marks: they are independent, but given Python, they're not different processes.)

Comment: Sometimes a trick is to figure out ahead of time which jobs will take the longest, and start those first.  This can improve overall time-to-completion without a complex scheduling algorithm (like bin packing).

Comment: your waiting will be constrained by the slowest. You can avoid waiting of ALL (just start and do other work). Also you can try to use processes instead of threads, in some kinds it can be better scheduled (I suppose the task's body is just a sample)

Comment: Yes, it is fire and forget.  The function does all that I need, it writes its response to the database.  I don't need the response.  I did think about removing the join, but was worried that wasn't the right thing to do.  I presume as long as I can cope with mid-exists, then removing the join would be OK?.  If I was to use multiprocessing.Process what would be the main benefit of that? Thanks everyone so far for your insight